# CodeIgniter JQuery Post Failed to read Json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to Jquery. I am trying to fetch some data from Codeigniter, I used Fiddler and validated my controller sends valid Json response back but JQuery is not triggering Function.

Here is my Jquery Post code.

```
 $.post('<?=base_url();?>index.php/location/get_state_city', {'state_id' : this.value,'city' : neighbor}, function(data) 
        {
            alert('inside function' + data);
        }, 'json');
```

Following is the response I am getting back from Codeigniter controller as shown in Fiddler

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Sun, 15 Oct 2017 07:20:21 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25
>   Content-Length: 125
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   {"data_type":"success","data_val":"Select City</option>BOSTON</option>","loc":"1"}

I also tried AJAX and it goes in Error function and shown this error.

> ajax "readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"

Ajax Code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Location/get_state_city'); ?>",
            data: postData,
            datatype : 'json',
            success: function(data){
                alert( "Data fetched: " + data );

            },error : function(data2) {
                alert('Failed' + JSON.stringify(data2));
                }
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your controller too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```php
 public function get_state_city(){
      $state_id = $this->input->post('state_id');
      $loc_res = $this->location_model->get_neighborhoodcity(array('where' => array('state_id' => $state_id), 'status' => '1', 'debug' => FALSE));
      $neigh   = (int)$this->input->post('city');
      if(is_array($loc_res) && !empty($loc_res)){
          $neighbour = '<option value="">Select City</option>';
          foreach($loc_res as $key => $val){
              $neighbour .= '<option value="'.$val['id'].'" '.($val['id'] == $neigh ? ' Selected = "selected"' : '').'>'.$val['name'].'</option>';
          }
         $neighbour, "loc" => $state_id);
          $loc_data = array('data_type' => 'success',"data_val" => $neighbour, 'loc' => $state_id);
      }else{
          $loc_data = array('data_type' => 'error', 'data_val' => '', 'loccccc' => $state_id);
      }

      echo json_encode($loc_data);  
}
```